# Different IP for the Windows Phone 8 emulator

Tags: networking, windows-phone-8, emulation, multicast

I'm doing a windows phone 8 app using networking.
However my IP from my computer / windows phone looks something like 198.168.xxx.xxx
Whereas on the emulator it's something like 169.xxx.xxx.xxx.

I'm quite new on networking programming, but I'm quite sure that I need to change the one from my emulator in order to allow the emulator and my windows phone to communicate.

What could I do to make the emulator's IP looks like the one from my laptop and allow my emulator to communicate with my windows phone?

Answer (score 0):

You are in one local network, it should work well. There is a [good multicast sample at](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh286407%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) msdn, you can build it and test to be sure.